# Setting up CiviCRM with Multisite Wordpress

Tags: multisite

Thanks in advance for any help or insights, I have an existing WordPress multisite install and we would like to have CiviCRM installed on all three sites but sharing the same database. I have followed the civimultisite documentation and the checklist posted here, but as soon as I hit the [install] on the 2nd site, I get this error: *"Found installation Canary” while installing CiviCRM"*. I have edited the civi settings php file adding the domains of the other 2 site per the documentation but no joy yet, any help will be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

i do this with a WPMU and civiCRM and it work fine. I m french, i dont speak english but i do a tutorial in french, i can give you this doc, my mail is pikerez@laposte.net. Goodbye

Comment: i changed 'tuto' to 'tutorial' as a 'best guess' for what was meant